# moving mouse fast, box is not repainted ~ JavaScript Only

Tags: javascript

```
function down(event){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor="green";
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",move,false);
}

function up(event) {
    event.target.style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove",move,false);
}

function move(event) {
    event.target.style.left=Math.max(0,Math.min(window.innerWidth-50,event.clientX-25))+"px";
    event.target.style.top=Math.max(0,Math.min(window.innerHeight-50,event.clientY-25))+"px";
}
```

Full code at->
http://jsfiddle.net/tcubsfbg/1/ 
Whenever i move mouse more fast, the box does not repainted at new position as fast as I am moving mouse.
 I added mouse move event to the window and even with the document, still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was how you attached the eventlisteners.

```
var box=document.getElementById("hello");
function init(){
    box.addEventListener("mousedown",down,false);
    box.addEventListener("mouseup",up,false);
}
function down(event){
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",move,false);
}
function move(event){
    box.style.left=event.clientX-50+"px";
    box.style.top=event.clientY-50+"px";
}
function up(event){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove",move,false);
}
window.onload=init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tcubsfbg/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tcubsfbg/1/
Can you try this too, Problem is same but not fixed with any way I attach handler

Comment: It might be faster to only attach the event-listeners once, and use a boolean flag value to indicate if they should do anything or not.